# ButtonClick is breaking program

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I am trying to implement onclick when i click first button to go to new window but when i click it breakes program. I have the error :

W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x97154160, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH.

This is main :

```
package FirstApp.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener{
TextView text;
Button button;
Button button2;
boolean onClick = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


}
@Override

public void onClick(View view) {


    if(view.getId() == R.id.button){

        text.setText("Prvi button je kliknut");

    }

    else if(view.getId() == R.id.button2){

       /* Intent i = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("TEXT", input.getText().toString());
        startActivity(i);/*/

        text.setText("Drugi button je kliknut");
    }
  }
 }
```

And this is second class :

```
package dvino.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


/**
  * Created by zeroOne on 26.5.2017..
*/

public class Dvino extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dvino);
  }


}
```

EDIT-this is error message that i recive when the program crashes:

```
<'E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: dvino.myapplication, PID: 3044
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method 
     OnClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute 
      defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 
    'button'
                      at 


 android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
                      at 


  android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)'
```

Main xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="dvino.myapplication.MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:text="D'vino"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="49dp"
        android:onClick="OnClick"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/dvino"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="D'vino Kitchen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_message"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Java is Case-Sensitive. `android:onClick="OnClick"` **does not match** `public void onClick(View view) {`

Answer (score 2):

You program is crashing because of a null pointer exception when you try to call `textview.setText()` - textview is null because you haven't initialized it yet.

the same way you did `button = (Button)findView...` you have to do that for the textview also

Comment: No it is still breaking after i initialized it

Comment: Ok, you have a separate error now. There is a bug in your xml file. Can you post that?

Comment: see Rotwang's comment. You need to match OnClick with onClick

Answer (score 0):

Your code have TextView problems and
this parts:
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener{}
change on:
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements 
View.OnClickListener{

edit---
Okey.Try it.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private Button button;
private TextView text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.testB);
    text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.testT);


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            button.setText("ClickedButton");
            text.setText("ChangedText");
        }
    });


}
```

}

Comment: When i do that it says - Cannot resolve symbol Activity

Comment: Now I see your xml file. If you can use upper code, remove this line   android:onClick="OnClick"

Answer (score 0):

Change `onclick="OnClick"`
To `onclick="onClick"` for your button widget with ID="button"

Remember use capital letters carefully ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate` method after the initialization of the button `button=(Button)findViewBy...` put `button.onClicklistener(this);`

Answer (score 0):

> `java.lang.IllegalStateException`: Could not find method `OnClick(View)`
>   in a parent or ancestor `Context` for `android:onClick` attribute defined
>   on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id
>   `'button'`

**1.** In your layout XML, change Button attribute `android:onClick` value to `onClick`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    ..........
    ...............
    tools:context="dvino.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <Button         
        android:id="@+id/button"
        ..........
        .................
        android:onClick="onClick" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        ..........
        ................
        android:onClick="onClick" />

    ...........
    .................

</RelativeLayout>
```

**2.** In your `MainActivity`, you are trying to set `Text` on an null `TextView` object as you did not get the `reference` of it from your attached `layout`. It may cause an `NullPointerException`. To avoid this exception update your activity `onCreate()` method as below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
}
```

Hope this will help~